# Можно ли генерировать документы .doc без предустановленного на сервере Word?

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, com, office

На арендуемом сервере невозможно создавать `COM`-объекты Excel и Word. Имеется код, который можно было бы перенести, но код этот реализован через COM-интерфейс.

Нельзя ли как-нибудь обойти эту проблему или придется все переписывать?

**UPD**
Придется переписывать. [Consideration for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757).

Comment: COM-объекты будут работать ТОЛЬКО на сервере с ОС windows и только c установленным Word / Excel

Comment: Да. В проект потребовалось включить только 2 ссылки:  
1. Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library (MSO.DLL)  
2. Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library (MSWORD.OLB)  
если их с собой таскать?  
Скопировать эти файлы в `~\Bin\` не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы через COM создаёте объект, например, Word.Application, - тогда без установленного офиса не обойтись.

Если вы документ открываете через OLE DB (тоже COM по сути), тогда на сервере достаточно установить [AccessDatabaseEngine](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) (обратите особое внимание, что 32-битная версия не работает в 64-битном процессе)

UPDATE
Через OLE DB точно можно открыть xls, насчёт doc я не проверял.

Comment: Создаем `Word.Application`. А что, и Word документы через OLE DB можно открывать?

Comment: И верно, OLE DB более относится к Excel, поэтому поправил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет установленных COM компонент, то прога использующая ее не сможет воспользоваться ими - соответственно вы не сможете сгенерировать DOC файлы.

Так что придется все переписывать или найти способ установки COM объектов.